# unordered_set range insertion VS iterator

Tags: c++, unordered-set

I am trying to understand why range insertion below is faster than using the iterator.

```
vector<string> &paths // 3 milion strings
```

Method 1 : range insert

```
unordered_set<string> mySet;
mySet.insert(paths.begin(), paths.end());
```

Method 2 : iterator

```
vector<string>::iterator row;
for (row = paths.begin(); row != paths.end(); row++)
{
  mySet.insert(row[0]);
}
```

Results :

Method 1 : 753 ms

Method 2 : 1221 ms

==============================

OS: Windows 10

IDE: visual studio code

Compiler: gcc version 8.1.0

Flags : -O3

Comment: I suspect with the range insert, the compiler is free to more aggressively optimize all the insertions. With the for loop and iterator, you are making that many independent calls to `.insert()` which likely does not lend itself to the same optimizations. You need to dump the assembly and take a look at what is happening with each.

Comment: @walnut, I am new to c++, I added some details, but not sure about standard library details you asked for?

Comment: @J.K The information is sufficient, the standard library implementation used by gcc is libstdc++. Now the code you used to benchmark would be ideal. Then we can reproduce the timings.

Comment: Since you have `g++` you can dump the assembly by compiling with the `"-S"` option. Also some find reading *intel* syntax a bit easier than *ATT*. If you have `gcc/g++` in your path, just open the Command Prompt (or PowerShell) and compile with `g++ -S -masm=intel -O3 -o myprog.asm myproc.c++`. The assembly will be in the file `myprog.asm`.

Comment: @DavidRankin-ReinstateMonica, I generated the assembly file, but I am still trying to find the range insertions. I have to check it more.

Comment: You can also dump for the different optimization levels (e.g. `-O0, ... -O3, -Ofast`) into separate assembly files if interested. I don't know if turning name-mangling off may make it easier to find in the assembly file, you will have to experiment. The smaller you can make your test case you are compiling, the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, the range insertion procedure should be faster. Imagine, for example, that you want to insert a million elements. If you do a range insert, the set can

1. count up how many total elements will be inserted to see how much space is needed;
2. allocate an array of buckets big enough to keep the load factor within appropriate limits, possibly moving all old elements over the new table; then
3. insert all the elements.

There are some further possible optimizations that could be done here (using a pooled allocator for bulk allocations, doing a multithreaded insertion procedure, etc.), though I’m not sure whether these are actually done.

On the other hand, if you insert things one at a time, each of these steps needs to be done a million times. That means there’s time and space wasted allocating intermediate arrays of buckets that don’t ultimately get used, but which the implementation can’t tell won’t be used because the implementation has to keep things in a good state every step of the way.

For an `unordered_set` these optimizations are just improvements to the expected O(1) cost per insertion. In some other containers like `vector` or `deque`, bulk inserts can be asymptotically faster than repeated individual inserts because the container can move other elements once during the bulk insert rather than doing lots of repeated shifts.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looking through the libstdc++ code, the first optimization you mentioned (rehash for the appropriate total insert size) is what it does. Aside from the rehashing policy, the same insert functions are used, so I don't think there is any other optimization done.

Comment: I didn't try pooled allocator yet. I am trying multithreaded and will update the post again if I get better results. Thank you for your answer.